# Nested lookup function for excel with multiple headers

Tags: microsoft-excel

I hope this is the correct channel for posting excel related questions.

I am currently stuck in performing a lookup function in an excel spreadsheet.

The data I have has the following structure:

[image]

I would like to create a lookup function where I specify:
the name of the header, the Type of subheader and the row name.
It should return the value in front of the  row name. E.g, If I lookup for Header one, Type A, val1-A it should return 1.

Any easy way to perform this task?

I will leave the example spreadsheet attached bellow
https://we.tl/t-MOnNSGroRG

Comment: I would use named ranges that incorporate Header and Type as the name then us INDIRECT to call the correct named range.

Comment: A similar question was asked about a month ago. What research on this site have you done?

Comment: Can you redirect me to that question? Maybe I can get Ideas on how to solve this

Comment: In Thomas' defense, I could not find the question gns100 mentioned. I like Scott's suggestion, but INDIRECT can be slow on large spreadsheets. You can also use `=VLOOKUP("val1-A",CHOOSE(i,table1,table2,...table5,table6),2)` and determine the CHOOSE index *i* based on your selection criteria, which in itself can be from a dropdown list. So i = (MATCH(K1, list1, 0)-1)*3 + MATCH(K2, list2, 0)

Comment: although there could be workarounds to solve your problem with current data structure, the sustainable way is to change your data structure. there should be just one table containing all information with specific column to header and sub-header.

Answer (score 0):

I picture the data beginning in A1 with "Header one" centered across the eight columns of the range, or those cells merged. Looks like two lines between "Header xxx" groupings. So 15 rows per grouping.

That places the lookup variables in K2:K4 with the result in K5.

I also picture the pic you gave being "dumbed down" for simplicity in the question and that all three variables actually need looked up rather than just doing a bunch of nested `IF`'s or a nice `IFS`. Considering the "Header xxx" terminology to be unique to those header lines, as in not shared elsewhere in column A. Same idea with the column pair headers ("A-B-C") and that those could really be anything, again herein simplified, but that they are in the leftmost column of each pair (so in A2 for the column A/B pair in "Header one" (centered across selection or merged).

Therefore, all variables really need looked up and could be anything, more or less, so no simplifying assumptions past the above.

The formula was tested on five such groups and so its range was the shown A1:H75. Since it is in the first row of the `LET`, it is EASILY accessed for changing.

As to the `LET`, if you don't have the function, it's no problem to substitute pieces into place. If you do, you might like to give the lookup variables names, on the second row perhaps, so the lookup table addresses could be easily changed. Maybe not as how often does one take a lookup table to somewhere else? I would suggest though to change the other row 1 name in the `LET`, "HeaderRange" from an explicit range to a single column `INDEX` of the Range name that precedes it so it changes automatically as the Range name is adjusted.

The formula:

```
=LET(Range,  A1:H75,  HeaderRange,  A1:A75,
      HeaderRow,  MATCH($K$2,HeaderRange,0),
      valColumn,  MATCH($K$3,INDEX(Range,1+HeaderRow,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Range))),0),
      val,  INDEX(Range,SEQUENCE(11,1,HeaderRow+2,1),valColumn),
      values,  INDEX(Range,SEQUENCE(11,1,HeaderRow+2,1),valColumn+1),

      XLOOKUP($K$4,val,values)
     )
```

Basically, it uses `MATCH` on the leftmost column of the data range to locate the row the "Header" variable is in. Adding 1 to that gets the row the "Type" variable is in. `MATCH` finds the column the "val" variables are in and returns that plus the next column over's column. Then `XLOOKUP` seeks the value associated with the "val" variable and returns that value.

The formula doesn't do any error checking of which having non-unique "val" labels in the same "Header xxx" section would be the most worrisome, past the usual typos and such anyway. So, if there were two or more "val2-A" entries in that column, it will not catch them. If there could be, and that not be a mistake to correct, and it was important to return all of them, `FILTER` could be used in the last step. If only one were desired, and not necessarily the first or last of them, rather, say, the `MAX` of them, but whichever, one would just keep wrapping the `FILTER` as needed until only one was returned.